# Как частично транспонировать DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Имеется такой DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(((1, 'Vasya', 13, 'Да', 'Было щекотно'),), columns=('user_id', 'user_name', 'poll_id', 'Тебе понравилось?', 'Дай комментарий'))
```

```
| user_id | user_name | poll_id | Тебе понравилось? | Дай комментарий |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Vasya | 13 | Да | Было щекотно |
```

А нужно его преобразовать в такой:

```
tdf = pd.DataFrame(((1, 'Vasya', 13, 'Тебе понравилось?', 'Да'), (1, 'Vasya', 13, 'Дай комментарий', 'Было щекотно')), columns=('user_id', 'user_name', 'poll_id', 'Вопрос', 'Ответ'))
```

|  | user_id | user_name | poll_id | Вопрос | Ответ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | Vasya | 13 | Тебе понравилось? | Да |
| 1 | 1 | Vasya | 13 | Дай комментарий | Было щекотно |

Но пока не выходит. Прошу подсказать, как это делается.

PS. В реальной таблице вспомогательных информационных полей намного больше. Но суть та же - нужно столбцы с вопросами разбить построчно, как в примере.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [DataFrame.stack()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
res = (df
       .set_index("user_id user_name  poll_id".split())
       .stack()
       .reset_index()
       .rename(columns={"level_3":"Вопрос", 0:"Ответ"}))
```

результат:

```
In [146]: res
Out[146]:
   user_id user_name  poll_id             Вопрос         Ответ
0        1     Vasya       13  Тебе понравилось?            Да
1        1     Vasya       13    Дай комментарий  Было щекотно
```

Comment: Здорово! То что нужно. Вы как обычно показываете класс в Pandas) А вот я редко к нему возвращаюсь и каждый раз как в первый. Не чувствую его.

Comment: @Alpensin, как обычно - это дело практики)